# Usage of '-' after pipe

Tags: linux, bash

I saw this line of code the other day and I didn't know exactly what is this - or when to use it. This is a simple code and from what I understood is that - takes the piped output and treats it as an argument of paste (correct me if I'am wrong)

```
seq $size | paste - $file
```

My question is when can we use this and is there another way to do the same thing?
Thanks,

Comment: It's not a shell-specific thing, it's understood by some programs (including `paste`) to mean "use standard input rather than a file".

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the man page for `paste` which says:

```
  With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
```

That is, `paste` expects you to give it a filename, but you can instead give it a single `-` instead, which paste will interpret as it should read data from `stdin` , your pipe in this case, instead of opening a file and read data from that file.

Comment: Many (but not all) commands understand `-` this way. When in doubt, check the man pages.